# Calculate ranking in mysql using update query

Tags: php, mysql

We have calculated ranking using following query.

```
set @rank = 0;
Update rank_table
     set position= (select @rank := @rank + 1)
     order by points DESC, points_new DESC, points_old DESC;
```

And it calculates ranking in sequence.

eg.

[image]

I want that id's having same criteria should assign same ranking.
so let say,
here id 1 and 2 have same criteria then should have position=1 and then id 3 should have position=3.
Not like current flow.
Currently -> Id 1:position 1 , Id 2:position 2 , Id 3:position 3 
but as Id 1 and 2 have same data it should be..

Id 1:position 1 , Id 2:position 1 , Id 3:position 3

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is technically `rank()` rather than `row_number()`.  This is something of a pain, but possible:

```
set @rn := 0;
set @rank := 0;
set @p := -1;
Update rank_table
     set position = if(@rn := @rn + 1,
                       if(@p = points, @rank,
                          if(@p := points, @rank := @rn, @rank := @rn)
                         ),
                       NULL -- never should happen
                      )
     order by points DESC, points_new DESC, points_old DESC;
```

This is tricky because you need to calculate both the rank and the row number -- the rank stays the same and then it must "jump" to the row number.

Comment: Great.. 
It worked. Thanks a lot. Was stucked in it.

Comment: Could you please explain what these lines do?
                        `  if(@p := points, @rank := @rn, @rank := @rn)`

Comment: @Bini . . . I don't understand your comment.  `:=` assigns values to variables.  `if()` is a conditional function.  These are basic parts of the MySQL language.  This is how to use them to implement the equivalent of `rank()` in other databases.